# Thai language Locale Setting problem in the android

Tags: android, locale, thai

I have some problem of localization.I have some content which have both Thai and english. when i run in the android2.1 Thai language show as Boxes. so have set that Thai language as locale in my activity as below

Locale local=new Locale("th","TH");
 Locale.setDefault(locale);

### Which is working in the Android2.3 but not working in the Android2.1. Please let me know where the mistake is? how can resolve this problem

By 
Akil

Answer (score 0):

Thai is not supported in 2.1

[Android 2.1 Platform notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html#locs)